# How can i pass this complex Json MAP Data into flutter Listview

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dart-pub

i am new to flutter, and i meet this API with complex "MAP" json. What i want is to display the list of countries with their details in flutter listview, How can i achieve that? Most of answers explain about "LIST" json.

```
 {
"status": "Request is successful",
"message": null,
"data": {
"page": 1,
"last_page": 125,
"page_size": 2,
"countries": [
        {
 "id": "1",
"attributes": {
"name": "Grenada",
 "code": "GD",
"subregion": "Caribbean",
"flag": "https://flagcdn.com/gd.svg",
"postalcode": "",
"latitude": "12.11666666",
"longitude": "-61.66666666",
"createdAt": "2023-01-11T22:15:40.000000Z",
"updatedAt": "2023-01-11T22:15:40.000000Z"
  }
 },
  {
"id": "2",
"attributes": {
 "name": "Malaysia",
 "code": "MY",
 "subregion": "South-Eastern Asia",
 "flag": "https://flagcdn.com/my.svg",
  "postalcode": "^(\\d{5})$",
 "latitude": "2.5",
  "longitude": "112.5",
  "createdAt": "2023-01-11T22:15:40.000000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2023-01-11T22:15:40.000000Z"
     }
     }
  ]
  }
  }
```

I found this [GitHub project](https://github.com/tsvillain/complexJson) with these files [json](https://github.com/tsvillain/complexJson/blob/master/lib/jsonResponse.json), [modelClass](https://github.com/tsvillain/complexJson/blob/master/lib/json.dart) [Mainclass](https://github.com/tsvillain/complexJson/blob/master/lib/main.dart) which relate with the concept but mine is has got one extra braces (map) so i do not know how to achieve the goal.

if there any suggestion or best way to code please help me.

this is how they created in model class but, but it does not work with me.

```
    class Product {
   final List<Result> results;
    Product({this.results});
    factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
     var list = data['data']['result'] as List;
    List<Result> resultList = list.map((e) => Result.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return Product(
    results: resultList,
    );
    }
    }
```

what i have done is

```
       class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

       @override
     State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
         }
      class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
     var data_from_link;
      getData() async {
      final String link = 'myurl';
      data_from_link = await http.get(Uri.parse(link), headers:    {"Accept": "application/json"});
     final res = jsonDecode(data_from_link.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final List<Country> list= (res['data']['countries'] as      List<dynamic>).map((e) => Country.fromJson(e))
    .toList();
  
          }

        @override
        void initState() {
           super.initState();
                 getData();
                  }
          @override
             Widget build(BuildContext context) {
             final res = jsonDecode(data_from_link.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
             final List<Country> list= (res['data']['countries'] as  List<dynamic>).map((e) => Country.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
        return  ListView.builder(
            itemCount: list.length,
         itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(
               title: Text(
                 list![i].attributes.name,
             ),
               subtitle: Text(list![i].attributes.code),
                 )
                 );
                }
               }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two classes for `Country` and `Attribute`

```
class Country {
  const Country({required this.id, required this.attributes});

  /// Creates a Country from Json map
  factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Country(
        id: json['id'] as String,
        attribute:
            Attribute.fromJson(json['attributes'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
      );

  /// A description for id
  final String id;
  final Attribute attributes;
}
```

```
class Attribute {
  const Attribute({
    required this.name,
    required this.code,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  /// Creates a Attribute from Json map
  factory Attribute.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Attribute(
        name: json['name'] as String,
        code: json['code'] as String,
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json['createdAt'] as String),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json['updatedAt'] as String),
      );

  final String name;
  final String code;
  final DateTime createdAt;
  final DateTime updatedAt;
}
```

when decoding:

```
  final res = jsonDecode(json) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  final List<Country> list = (res['data']['countries'] as 
  List<dynamic>)
        .map((e) => Country.fromJson(e))
        .toList();
```

> Thank you but how can i print or call data from country attribute
> after decoding because when i try something like Print
> (list.country.attribute.name) . I fail. My goal is to display on
> Listview

You can use it like this:

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  list[i].attributes.name,
                ),
                subtitle: Text(list[i].attributes.code),
              )),
```

[image]

> **UPDATE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  late Future<List<Country>> futureList;
  Future<List<Country>?> getData() async {
    final String link = 'yoururl';
    final res = await http
        .get(Uri.parse(link), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<Country> list = (res['data']['countries'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => Country.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
      return list;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch data');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureList = getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: futureList,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final list = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: list!.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(
              title: Text(
                list![i].attributes.name,
              ),
              subtitle: Text(list![i].attributes.code),
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('error fetching data');
        }
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  but how can i print or call data from country attribute after decoding  because when i try something like Print (list.country.attribute.name) . I fail. My goal is to display on Listview. Please man help me i have four days try to figure it out

Comment: i followed what you showed me and i get this error 'body'
method not found
Receiver: null
Arguments: [] let me edit the part question  so that you can see

Comment: After first adding material widget like Scaffold widget, before FutureBuilder, second adding  final response= jsonDecode(res.body) as Map<String, dynamic>; and third after replacing res['data'] with response['data'] it finally worked.